# Commutative relation in rectangle of homologies

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, modules, homology-cohomology, exact-sequence

[image]

By short-sequences the exercise means sequences where $Im \ f \subset Ker \ g$.

These $H_n$ are homologies, analogous to this [construction for groups](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homology_(mathematics)#Construction_of_homology_groups), but here it's for modules. Normally I'd show my thinking, but for this exercise I don't even know where to start. Obviously I must show that $\alpha_{*}\circ \partial = \partial'\circ \gamma$, but what is this $_*$?

I'd be grateful for some clarification and I antecipate that I'm opening a bounty to reward an answer for this one. Thank you.

Comment: $\alpha$ is a map of modules; $\alpha_{*}$ is the associated map on homology (which is also, in the second diagram), called "$H_{n-1}(\alpha)$"). So the thing you're asked to prove is that the second diagram is actually a commutative diagram.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry but I can't comment yet, so I'll put a brief answer.

First the $_*$ is pushforward / direct image of algebraic cycles. What you are asked to do is prove commutativity of the second diagram.   Have you heard of / constructed the "long exact sequence" induced by a short exact sequence yet? That may help.